# what is the importance of xml schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

hi I have created an XML file but now I have to create an XML schema.Can you guys tell me the importance of schema and the meaning of the line code.

`<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.abc.org/2010/XMLSchema">`

from where would I get the url just like above?

Comment: An XML schema describes the valid form and content of a conforming XML document. It is not required that every XML document has a corresponding schema, but it is important to have if you actually want to have others consume your documents.

So, what are these documents going to be used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your document is supposed to be an XML schema, then it must start

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

You can use a different namespace prefix if you like (some people prefer "xsd" to "xs") but the namespace URI must be exactly as written. It's a URI not a URL - a symbolic constant that identifies the XML vocabulary as being the XML schema vocabulary. If you use a different namespace, then it's not an XML schema any more.

Answer (score 7):

The schema is used to validate a document, and to assist people/programs from creating their own versions of XML according to the schema.